# Flutter. How to collapse GridView.builder when it empty (do not have any elements)

Tags: flutter, flutter-gridview

I have a GridView.builder with shrinkWrap to true. It fills dynamically, but the problem that at start it empty but takes place, like it has elements (sort of reserving place) depends on the size of maxCrossAxisExtent.
Is it possible change this? Empty space not very good..
I looked docs and google but didnt find any answer.

This is the code

```
class _PhotosState extends State<Photos> {
  List<File> photos = [];

  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

  Widget getGrid() {
    return Container(
      child: GridView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics:  NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(

          maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
          //childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
          // crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          // mainAxisSpacing: 10,
          //mainAxisExtent: 200,
        ),
        itemCount: photos.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.blueGrey,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

The empty GridView with empty space
[image: empty space when grid is empty]

One element added to GridView
[image: one element added]

Comment: @YeasinSheikh thanks for editing my post!  I use it like so  SliverToBoxAdapter(child:Photos())  The Photos is my StatefullWidget

Comment: let me know if my answer solve in your case.

Comment: Thnks for answer @gtxtreme what do you mean by FutureBuilder? It is some widget right? I new to flutter and cant get it.. I do not use FutureBuilder at this place. Can you detalize please if possible?

Comment: Thanks @YeasinSheikh it works, I marked your answer as right and asked new question below your answer))

Comment: I will try to answer your question asap after reproducing the errors and  testing myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
  Widget getGrid() {
    return photos.length<1?SizedBox():
           Container(
      child: GridView.builder(
```

Comment: Thanks @YeasinSheikh it works, but it sort of workaroud ? If it not very hard can you please explain where this empty space comes from and why if I use shrinkWrap actually?

Comment: Based on my observation `SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent` will always take `maxCrossAxisExtent`in this case 200 width because of its default aspect ratio is 1x1. It is taking height. I assume it's splitting the width before assigning child.
 Maybe it is just a bug that I'm not sure of it. 

If you look at the source code,  I think it is coming from `getLayout`()

Comment: Thanks for you help and time @Yeasin!